# Change username in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

if i go to 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapi/changename/1/', and put {"username":"abc"}, then it response, {"response": "something went wrong"}.

how to change the username of the user?

everything is imported properly.
i think my concept is not clear
here is my main code:

in views.py:

```
@api_view(['PUT'])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
def changeName(request,pk):
    user = User.objects.get(id=pk)
    serializer = UserSerializers(instance=user, data=request.data)
    
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
    else:
        return Response({'response': 'something went wrong'})
        
    return Response({'response': 'ok'})
```

in serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

in urls.py:

````
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('myapi/', views.apiView, name='apiView'),
    path('myapi/changename/<str:pk>/', views.changeName, name='changeName'),

]```
````

Comment: Try `return Response(serializer.errors)` instead of `return Response({'response': 'something went wrong'})`. This will tell you want went wrong.

Comment: UserSerializers(instance=user, data=request.data, partial=True)

Comment: @Marin , thanks. it works.

Comment: @TonyJoseph, thanks for your suggestion, it's helpful